# Small popup for instructions... How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to get a popup appear the first time an app is started. Just to give you an idea check the new version of foursquare. A small popup (like a comic) appear explaining where the checkin button is located. Then if you tap anywhere it goes away. I googled for the last hour but I have not found anything at all and I have no idea on how to do it.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Umberto

Comment: check you this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363529/client-side-feature-tour-tutorial-instructional-overlay-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show a customized UIlabel on app's load and then use performSelectorAfterDelay: and hide the label inside this method. For the tapping thing you can add a UITapGesture on your view to notify if some tap's occurred and hide the label if it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at TapKu by Devin Ross http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-alerts-with-images