# how to do small popup in android

Tags: android, popup

Two years after that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7051964/2969783) was asked, I want to know, if in the new versions of Android, there is a simple way to do it?

Comment: I think no but what is hard on [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) when all what you need is to just copy and paste code to your project?

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ Use This. It is quite Easy. Android does not provide by default. It does provide a popup windows but this QuickAction is quite much better. IF you want android's popoverview, you have to wait till monday

Comment: @RahulGupta it is exactly what I mean, if some thing like PopupView exists??

Comment: @Geralt, I think that I will work with, thank you.

Comment: please I need an answer to submit and close this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this :-

https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView

I used this. It extends a Relative Layout and Create a PopOver. I was talking about this only

Comment: please these classes of QuickAction and ItemAction,... are not included in standard APK, is it?

Comment: I didn't even said they did. The above link contains a popoverview made using android widgets and classes only