# Tutorial mode highlighter for a website

Tags: css

Trying to find a way in which I can code or use some OS code of "tutorial mode" like in mobile games. In which case, after pressing a button, you get into a tutorial that makes the background dark and each step its highlights a different part with explanation about it, as this poorly image I made shows (attached).[image: Highlights a part of the website (in this case a button), and gives an explanation about it]

I couldn't find the right term or how do I do is (probably using CSS). Would appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be better achieved with Javascript as well as CSS.

Use css to style the overlay elements and use javascript to change the content and positioning.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Yet, is there any templates or any source code I can learn from how to do so?

Comment: I just found that this question has been asked previously. The term you are looking for is "featured tour" and there is a huge amount of frameworks to choose from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363529/client-side-feature-tour-tutorial-instructional-overlay-system

Comment: Really do appreciate it! Thank you ever so much!